# Rank of partitions in T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

Given the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE #values (ID int, TYPE nchar(2), NUMBER int)

INSERT INTO #values values (1, 'A', 0)
INSERT INTO #values values (2, 'A', 0)
INSERT INTO #values values (3, 'B', 1)
INSERT INTO #values values (4, 'A', 1)
INSERT INTO #values values (5, 'B', 2)

SELECT * FROM #values
```

I would like to generate this table:

```
   Id | T | N | COUNT
   ------------------ 
    1 | A | 0 | 1000
    2 | A | 0 | 1000
    3 | B | 1 | 1001
    4 | A | 1 | 1002
    5 | B | 2 | 1003
```

How can I do this in T-SQL?

I've been fiddling with `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY)` but this does not solve the problem, as it resets the count at each partition, which is not what I would like to do.

Comment: Could you explain the logic behind "count" in a bit more detail than "this does not solve it"?

Comment: @mo5470: Do you wish to have a count by type so you have a count of how many types or do you wish to count by type and number?

Once you answer could provide more help, but thinking you could do a GROUP BY - for example:

SELECT [Type], [Number], Count([Number]) AS aCount FROM #values GROUP BY [Type], [Number];

Comment: @PCPGMR, I want a count by type and number.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, my "count" field is a number assigned to a pair of Type and Number

Comment: @mo5470 So the order of A/1 and B/1 are irrelevant as long as they're numbered differently? Or is the id order relevant? What would in that case A/1,B/1,A/1 count as? Also, the version of SQL server may be relevant.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, the order is irrelevant, yes. For A/1, B/1, A/1 the count would be 1000/1001/1000

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for `dense_rank`:

```
SELECT 
 ID,
 TYPE,
 NUMBER,
 DENSE_RANK() over (order by TYPE, Number)
FROM #values
```

This produces

```
1   A   0   1
2   A   0   1
4   A   1   2
3   B   1   3
5   B   2   4
```